# using server hosted otf font in my webpage

Tags: html, fonts, webfonts, google-fonts

In my webpage, using google web fonts is ok.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">

<div style="font-family: 'Source Code Pro';">My Text</div>
```

it's ok using like this. But I've server hosted .otf font and I want to use it on my webpage, I've tried using like

```
 @font-face {
            font-family: 'MyFontName';
            src: url("https://www.mywebsitepage.com/fonts/MyHostedFont.otf") format("opentype");
        }

<div style="font-family: 'MyFontName';">My Text</div>
```

But it doesn't work. The reason why use my font is I can't find my font in free google web fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your sample, I hope that not the case you are really using it. I mean you have separate **.css** file which includes the `font-face` declaration and you attach this file in the `head` of your document, or using it like a part of `<style>...</style>` construction better also in `head` of document. If yes, so you can try to not use .otf, but using .woff and .woff2 instead.

It's not proper way to use **.otf** for web fonts now. Currently, if you don't really need support old versions of IE (8 and lower) you can just load fonts in **.woff** and **.woff2** formats and that will cover your needs.
Like this:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: "Open Sans";
 src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
        url("/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff") format("woff");
}
```

If you have .otf font you can really easy convert it to need web-font formats using some online generators like https://transfonter.org/ or similar.